# Submit iOS App to App Store from Group company's Apple Account

Tags: ios, app-store, app-distribution

We have two companies A and B under one group. Can I submit My App to app store for Company B using Company A's Developer/iTunes Connect Account?

Or do I need to create a Different Developer Account using a different DUNS Number. Or can I transfer app in future to company B's Account as it will take time for us to compete all legal procedure.

Will Apple approve that? This app will be Free on the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a separate Developer Account for the the Company B and use it to submit your Company B application to the App Store (for review).

Otherwise your app might get reject by Apple with a statement similar than the following:

> The seller and company names associated with your app do not reflect the name, "Company B" in the app or its metadata, as required by section 1.2 of the Apple Developer Program License Agreement.

The relevant section of the Apple Developer Program License Agreement:

> For the sake of clarity, You may authorize contractors to develop Applications on Your behalf, but any such Applications must be owned by You, submitted under Your own developer account, and distributed as Applications only as expressly permitted herein. You are responsible to Apple for Your contractors’ activities under Your account (e.g., adding them to Your team to perform development work for You) and their compliance with this Agreement. Any actions undertaken by Your contractors arising out of this Agreement shall be deemed to have been taken by You, and You (in addition to Your contractors) shall be responsible to Apple for all such actions.

However, if the Company B is not a well known brand, Apple might not notice this violation and might approve the app. I am not advising doing that, but there are many apps violating this.

It is also possible to transfer an app from one developer (company) to another. To learn more see iTunes Connect Developer Guide - [Transferring and Deleting Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html). I have never personally done it so don't know how much hassle it is. If you are thinking about transferring the app later, it might easier to release the app under the correct company in the first place.

Also note that if you have not yet released any app under the Company A account, the first time you release an app, you need to pick a seller name that is used for all apps released under this account and cannot be changed (unless you contact iTunes Connect support). So if you pick "Company B" as the seller name, all the future apps will have "Company B" as the seller name.